# problem: Getting to the element by using CSS selectors attribute 'style' with selenium

Tags: python, xpath, selenium, css-selectors

I'm having trouble getting to the element using the 'style' attribute with selenium. The problem is that using xpath selectors I am able to do it:

```
int(self.selenium.get_element_index("//div[contains(@class,'%s')][contains(@style,'%s')][contains(@style,'%s')]"%(pin_class_name,map_object_position[0],map_object_position[1])))
```

^ This returns result

But when I try to get to the element using css selectors, it appears that such an element not found:

```
int(self.selenium.get_element_index("css=div[class*='%s'][style*='%s'][style*='%s']"%(pin_class_name,map_object_position[0],map_object_position[1])))
```

Has anyone met with this problem or knows if it is possible to navigate using the attribute 'style' using css selectors. I describe this problem, because I want to make a comparison with the use of both methods (I suspect that the use of xpath doesn't as it should)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did extensive experimentation comparing and contrasting XPath, CSS, and DOM locators for Selenium and found that while one can access the `style` attribute from XPath or DOM, one *cannot* from CSS (just as you surmised). You can find that tidbit (see Footnote 2), along with my complete analysis, in my quick reference chart [XPath, CSS, DOM and Selenium: The Rosetta Stone](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/), recently published on Simple-Talk.com.

Answer (score 0):

The `*=` operator isn't in CSS2, so depending on the version of Selenium you're using, it may not be available to you.